# Managing library dependencies using git

Tags: c++, c, git, version-control

I have a project which is built for multiple OSes(Linux and Windows for now, maybe OS X) and processors. To this project I have a handful of library dependencies, which are manly external but I have a couple of internal ones, in source form which I compile(cross-compile) for each OS-processor combination possible in my context.

Most of the external libraries are not changed very often, just maybe in case of a local bugfix or some feature\bugfix implemented in a newer version I think it may benefit the project. The internal libraries change quite often(1 month cycles) and are provided by another team in my company in binary form, although I also have access to the source code and if I need a bug to be fixed I can do that and generate new binaries for my usage until the next release cycle. The setup I have right now is the following(filesystem only):

```
-- dependencies
  |
   -- library_A_v1.0
     |
      --include
     |
      --lib
  |
   -- library_A_v1.2
     |
      --include
     |
      --lib
  |       
   -- library_B
     |
      --include
     |
      --lib
  | ...
```

The libraries are kept on a server and every time I make an update I have to copy any new binaries and header files on the server. The synchronization on the client side is done using a file synchronization utility. Of course any updates to the libraries need to be announced to the other developers and everyone has to remember to synchronize their "dependencies" folder.

Needless to say that I don't like very much this scheme. So I was thinking of putting my libraries under version control(GIT). Build them, pack them in a tgz\zip and push them on the repo. Each library would have its own git repository so that I could easily tag\branch already used versions and test drive new versions. A "stream" of data for each library that I could easily get, combine, update. I would like to have the following:

- get rid of this normal filesystem way of keeping the libraries; right now complete separate folders are kept and managed for each OS and each version and sometimes they get out of sync resulting in a mess
- more control over it, to be able to have a clear history of which versions of the libs we used for which version of our project; much like what we can obtain from git(VCS) with our source code
- be able to tag\branch the versions of the dependencies I'm using(for each and every one of them); I have my v2.0.0 tag/branch for library_A from which I normally take it for my project but I would like to test drive the 2.1.0 version, so I just build it, push it on the server on a different branch and call my build script with this particular dependency pointing to the new branch
- have simpler build scripts - just pull the sources from the server, pull the dependencies and build; that would allow also to use different versions of the same library for different processor-OS combinations(more than often we need that)

I tried to find some alternatives to the direct git based solution but without much success - like [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) which kind of seems overly complicated for what I'm trying to do.

What I'm facing right now is the fact that there seems to be very strong opinion against putting binary files under git or any VCS(although technically I would have also header files; I could also push the folder structure that I described directly to git to not have the tgz\zip, but I would still have the libraries binaries) and that some of my colleagues, driven by that shared strong opinion, are against this scheme of things. I perfectly understand **that git tracks content and not files**, but to some extent I will be tracking also content and I believe it will definitely be an improvement over the current scheme of things we have right now.

What would be a better solution to this situation? Do you know of any alternatives to the git(VCS) based scheme of things? Would it be such a monstrous thing to have my scheme under git :)? Please share your opinions and especially your experience in handling these types of situations.

Thanks

Comment: Better than what my company does: uses PDMWorks for binary release change control.  You know, right next to mechanical drawings, and word documents.  UGH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative, which would still follwo your project, would be to use [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/), which would allow you track header files, while keeping binaries stored elsewhere.
Then each git repo can be added as a [submodule](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) to your main project.

Comment: I already looked at that. It does not seem to fit too good with my needs. I'm not sure keeping apart the headers from the binaries is a good idea as they are dependent on each other - new versions of the libraries might add to the API and bring new versions of the headers into the picture. I would very much like not to separate them.

Comment: @celavek: they won't be separated, logically. They will look as part of the same Git repo. It is only the large binary content itself which would be stored elsewhere. But from a Git client's perspective, they are all in the same repo.

Comment: Indeed logically they will be separate but git-annex doesn't seem to allow to keep multiple versions of the libraries. It looks that I will end up using kind of like the same folder based approach I'm using now. Can I branch and tag using git-annex? It doesn't seem to be that way from the documentation ... I'll look further, but it feels that is doesn't provide what I would really want.

Comment: @cevalak: "Indeed logically they will be separate "... Errr, no, my point was that, logically, they **won't be separated**. "Can I branch and tag using git-annex?". Sure, the all point to git-annex is to make look like those big files are there in the Git repo (with all its usual operations, like branching and tagging) except the *physical* content of those large files is stored elsewhere.

Comment: @cevelak: from the man page: http://git-annex.branchable.com/git-annex/ "Even without file content tracking, being able to manage files with git, move files around and delete files with versioned directory trees, and use branches and distributed clones, are all very handy reasons to use git. And annexed files can co-exist in the same git repository with regularly versioned files, which is convenient for maintaining documents, Makefiles, etc that are associated with annexed files but that benefit from full revision control.". Looks a good fit to me.

Comment: "logically, they won't be separated." - that's what I meant ... just a typo ... I will just try to deploy it(git-annex) and see how it goes from there as so far it seems to be the only alternative. Thanks for the help!